# Allocation Strategies For Queued Objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, queue

I have a class as follows:

```
typedef struct grid_cell_type {
int x;
int y;
grid_cell_type(int x0, int y0){
    x=x0;
    y=y0;
}
```

} grid_cell;

I'll be pumping approximately 100 million of these through a queue.

Right now, this happens as follows:

```
my_queue.push(new grid_cell(x0,y0));
```

The individual piece-wise allocation of all these objects seems as though it is probably not as quick as some mass-allocation.

Any thoughts as to the best strategy to pursue here?

Comment: Do you need to push pointers ? You could push values and save the trouble and speed impact of allocating dynamic memory yourself.

Comment: No, the pointers are because I'm not sure how to push a new `grid_cell` instance onto the queue without having that happen in this fashion.

Comment: @Richard : Just do this: `my_queue.push(grid_cell(x0,y0));`

Comment: But, @EmileCormier, is this different from doing a piece-wise allocation?

Comment: @Richard: How are you actually using your data? Your usage of it depends on the best allocation strategy.

Comment: @Richard : Conceptually, `my_queue.push(grid_cell(x0,y0))` creates a temporary `grid_cell` object on the stack, then copies it to the next position in the queue. With optimization enabled, the compiler will most likely just directly assign the `x0, y0` variables directly to their destination in the queue's storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are small and self-contained objects - put them directly in the queue instead of putting the pointers.

- In fact, on a 64-bit system and assuming `int` is 32-bit (which it is, for example, under Visual C++), the pointer will be as large as the object itself! So even if you have a bulk allocator, you still pay this price.
- The general memory allocator will not just be expensive time-wise, it will also have a per-object overhead, which in this case will dwarf the object itself (does not apply for bulk allocator).

While you *could* devise a fairly efficient "bulk" allocation scheme, I think it's simpler to sidestep the issue and altogether avoid the individual object allocations.

**--- EDIT ---**

You can push elements to the `std::queue` like this:

```
struct grid_cell {

    grid_cell(int x0, int y0) {
        x=x0;
        y=y0;
    }

    int x;
    int y;

};

// ...

std::queue<grid_cell> q;

q.push(grid_cell(0, 0));
q.push(grid_cell(0, 1));
q.push(grid_cell(0, 2));
q.push(grid_cell(1, 0));
q.push(grid_cell(1, 1));
q.push(grid_cell(1, 2));
```

For the `std::priority_queue`, you'd need to decide how you want to **order** the elements.

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

@Richard Your code is quite different.

- For each `push`, your code would allocate a new block of dynamic memory, construct the object in it (i.e. assign `x` and `y`) and then push the **pointer** to that block of memory to the queue.
- My code constructs the object directly in its "slot" within the larger memory block that was pre-allocated by the `queue` itself. And as you already noted, few big allocations 
  are better than many small ones.

Your code is:

1. prone to memory leaks
2. you pay for extra storage for pointers,
3. prone to memory fragmentation and
4. there is a per-object overhead, as I already mentioned.

A specialized bulk allocator could remove the last two problems but why not remove them all?

**--- EDIT 3 ---**

As for speed, the general dynamic memory allocation is **expensive** (about 40-50 machine instructions for best allocators).

The specialized block allocator would be much faster, but you still have an issue of memory latency: keeping everything nicely together is guaranteed to achieve better cache locality and be much more suitable for CPU's prefetching logic than repeatedly "jumping" between the queue and the actual objects by de-referencing pointers.

Comment: Thoughts on how one pushes the object directly onto the queue rather than the pointer? The code for this evades me.

Comment: @Richard Are you using `deque`?

Comment: I'm using a `std::priority_queue` with a vector as the underlying container, and an `std::queue` with the default container underlying (I believe this is a `deque`).

Comment: Thanks, @Branko. I do have an ordering method for `std::priority_queue`. If I do it in this way, is this different from doing a piece-wise, one-at-a-time allocation? It looks so similar...

Comment: @Richard: The one-at-a-time allocation strategy will technically take up more memory. Each allocation allocates 8 bytes for the cell and then another 4 or 8 (depending on 32 or 64-bit) for the pointer to the cell. The behavior between them should be the same, just this one will be easier to clean up because you won't have to `delete` each cell.

Comment: But @Kyle, memory is unimportant to me. Clean-up mess is fine. All I need is speed. Just speed. Raw, unadulterated speed.

Comment: @Richard: Well first off, you need to profile what you have now so you can determine how slow it really is. Premature optimization is the root of all evil afterall. :) But if you really do need speed, then the solution I mentioned could be faster than Branko's. If you allocate all your cells in one big chunk, it should be more cache friendly for the CPU. This depends entirely on what you're doing with your data of course, but the point stands. Large contiguous blocks of memory are generally best for memory performance.

Comment: @Kyle The `queue` will allocate "one big chink" already. By using pointers, you are not just paying the price for extra pointer de-reference, you are also de-coupling the position of objects in memory from their position in the queue, so you'll actually _lower_ the cache locality.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: Ahh, I'm not quite as familiar with the allocation strategies of the various STL containers. Good to know that the queue allocates like a vector (as it should) :)

Comment: @Kyle Actually, the minimal granularity for memory allocator under Visual C++ is 16 bytes. So there will be 16 bytes for the object itself + 4 to 8 bytes for the pointer, for a total of 20 to 24 bytes for  8 bytes of useful data (assuming `int` is 32-bit)! Other allocators may have lower granularity (8 being typical on Linux if I'm not mistaken), but this is not something to be relied upon.

Comment: @Kyle Yup, the default "underlying" container for the `queue` is `deque`, which is essentially a continuous a slab of memory, just like `vector`.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic : There's no requirement for a `deque` to use contiguous memory. A `deque` uses a series of blocks of memory. See this article for a description of the differences between `vector` and `deque`: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Comment: @EmileCormier Thanks, I didn't know that! Fortunately, this is even better for the performance in this context, provided the `deque` chunks are large enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could do one big array of them and allocate out of it.

```
int allocation_index = 0;
grid_cell_type* cells = new grid_cell_type[100*1000*100];
my_queue.push(&cells[allocation_index++]);
```

You'll then avoid the overhead of 100 million little news. Cleanup is then as simple as `delete [] cells;`.

**EDIT:** In this particular case, what Branko said is probably your best bet. Assuming you're using `std::queue`, it will automatically allocate the memory you need. What I suggested would be better suited for larger objects.